# using BitmapData.draw() on a streaming (RTMP) .f4v with OSMF

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata, osmf

I am trying to use BitmapData.draw() on a video object, but using the OSMF framework.

My hosting service has set up the following so that I can access my rtmp video:

```
<VideoSampleAccess enabled="true">/</VideoSampleAccess>
```

Simplified code is as follows:

```
_videoURL = "my-url-here"       
resource = new StreamingURLResource(_videoURL);
videoElement = new VideoElement(resource);          
_player.media = videoElement; 
container.addMediaElement(videoElement);
_player.autoPlay = true;
_player.play();

// later on, pause the player at the end
_player.pause();
// get the Video object
videoObj = _player.displayObject as Video;
// detach the netstream
videoObj.attachNetStream(null);

// get the bitmap from the Video object and draw on it..
bmpdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(videoObj);

 bmpdata.draw()
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
SecurityError: Error #2135: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are streaming from Adobe Media Server the parameter needs to be set server side
http://www.shell-tips.com/2009/08/30/flash-how-to-fix-the-security-sandbox-violation-bitmapdata-draw/ 
I came across this when I attempted to create a reflection of the video stream under the video player.  Most CDN's will allow you to customize your media server application code... If not you need to change CDN's or switch to progressive playback

Comment: See, that's totally what I thought! My hosting service keeps claiming that I need to change a cross-domain file and I knew that was bunk.

Answer (score 0):

You could try drawing the container instead of the video object itself. The source for the draw method can be either of type Bitmap or DisplayObject , so any MovieClip or Sprite that adds your video should be drawable.

Edit:
You're right, wasn't really thinking ,if there's a security issue, drawing the container won't change much...

You could try this:

```
import flash.system.Security;

Security.loadPolicyFile('policyfileURL');
```

Comment: Hm, I think that helps, but I am still getting a security Error. Is there any way to set checkPolicyFile = true using OSMF?